# Authenticating via Sites.Selected and m365 cli

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, spfx

### Background

- We are using Azure DevOps Pipelines to deploy a SPFx package to a SharePoint online site collection app catalog
- Deployments are being done in a PowerShell task using the M365 CLI
- Authentication is done by an AD app registration and a certificate with Sites.Selected access
- Sites.Selected has been granted with FullControl on the target site
- We are using `m365 spo app instance list` to determine if the app has already been added to the site, so we know if we need to install or upgrade the package

### Problem

- The `m365 spo app instance list` command returns an empty array even if there are multiple SPFx packages added to the site

### Investigation So Far

- The `m365 spo app instance list` command calls https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_api/web/AppTiles?$filter=AppType%20eq%203
- Browing to the url in an authenticated session with a user which has owner access brings back the data as expected
- Using Postman with the url and the bearer token taken from the pipeline step confirms an empty array is being returned
- Removing the filter in Postman returns other data correctly (all the lists and libraries on the site) but not the SPFx apps added to the site
- It appears authenticating via a certificate and Sites.Selected FullControl does not have access to see the installed SPFx apps

Anyone come across this issue before?